# How to generate OMA DM synchML request/response dynamically

Tags: java, windows-phone-8.1, mdm, oma-dm

I am implementing MDM solution for windows phone 8.1 and able to do enrollment and OMA DM synchML communication with device. So far I have tested with hard coded responses to device(e.g device lock CSP or device ring command). I have implemented my webservice in Java.

Can anybody tell me if any framework/jar is present to dynamically create synchML xml messages ? We can manage xml through XML parsers but is there anything specific for synchML support in java?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Ganesh Shinde

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/funambol - Should be useful.
- https://sourceforge.net/p/oma-scts/ A very old test suite for SyncML/OM-DS/DM.  Not sure if it would really be usable or not.
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/openoma Open OMA DM solution.  Again, not really sure how well it would work.